# Special Characters in Apache Velocity

Tags: apache, tomcat, velocity

How do I get Special Characters to show up in Apache Velocity as a string?
 something like:

```
#include("  <Bundle>")
#include("   <Description>$!{bundle.description}</Description>")
#include("  </Bundle>")
```

Comment: Would you please post desired output and, if relevant, the source you read from. `#include` 'Renders local file(s) that are not parsed by Velocity' as is reads in the [documentation](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/vtl-reference-guide.html). What are 'Special Characters' here?

Comment: I'm posting as much as I feel comfortable at the moment, but desired output would be string literals *everything in the quotations" special characters would be the carrots "<" and ">" plus the "/". so that The incoming values will create an XML file, the current way is doing text files, I'm just modifying the template to make an XML instead.

Comment: Got it. I guess this [part of the doc](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/developer-guide.html#Velocity_and_XML) will actually help. They are talking of different methods of escaping here.

Answer (score 0):

you can use velocity escape tool.

https://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/generic/EscapeTool.html

Comment: This link 404s.

Comment: https://velocity.apache.org/tools/1.4/generic/EscapeTool.html.. try this

Answer (score 0):

I took out the includes and it wrote it all as I needed it.